# Need to extract multiple Dates from single string

Tags: excel

I want output of dates in other columns. Example is

```
column A: Support to STARR APP01/01/15-31/12/15
Output in next columns
Column B: 01/01/15 and
Column C: 31/12/15.
```

Comment: The answer to this question strongly depends on the nature of the cells in question. If the dates are **always** in that format, a regular expression should do exactly what you need. If not, more examples of how they could be different are necessary.

Comment: is it always just 2 dates in each cell and you always want the first 1 in b and the second in c?

Answer (score 0):

If your string is in the same format, as you've said in your comment it is, you can just use a combination of left and right and possibly datevalue if you want the output to be forced into a date and not just be a string.

`=DATEVALUE(LEFT(RIGHT(SOURCECELL, 17),8))`
This should get the left date

`=DATEVALUE(RIGHT(SOURCECELL, 8))`
and this the right one.